Unable to get all rows from csv based on some column value
I am confused about how to get all the matching some value, I went through to all the related post on such topic on stackoverflow, what I have right now should be working, I am unsure either this csv is corupted, or am I making some mistake, so far I have this:
Data Sample

Now if I try to get the rows based on School Name, it works:
df_masterdb[df_masterdb['School Name'] == "Daniel Pratt Elementary School"]


But if I try to get rows based on State_abrr, it fetches me nothing:
df_masterdb[df_masterdb['State_abrr'] == "AL"]


Every column is working as expcted and fetches me all the required rows by above method but this "State_abrr" column fetches me nothing. Am I missing something here?

Your question is not reproducible, check for dangling spaces, special characters, case... What is the output of df_masterdb['State_abrr'].unique()?

You could also test to check if df_masterdb[df_masterdb['School Name'].str.contains('AL')] gets you any results. *This should get around any dangling spaces but will be stumped if any of the characters are non-standard

so it turns out, it was empty space after each value, after following @mozway's suggestion, solution:
df_masterdb['State_abrr'] = df_masterdb['State_abrr'].apply(lambda x : x.strip())
